# Is there a way to use __getattr__ as Python classmethod

Tags: python-3.x, oop, getattr

**getattr** works pretty well with instance of class:

```
class Person:

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print(name)

p = Person()
p.john
```

Output:

```
john
```

but it does not work as classmethod:

```
class Person:

    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        print(name)

Person.john
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'john'
```

Is there a way to use **getattr** for class directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__getattr__`, like most special methods, is only looked up on the class of the instance (bypassing the instance itself). Since you're trying to call it on the class itself, it has to be defined on the class that `class Person` is implementing. By default that's `type` (the common root for all class types).

If you *really* need to do this (I suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040)) you can do this with a metaclass (the class of the class itself):

```
class PersonMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        print(cls, name)

class Person(metaclass=PersonMeta):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(type(self), name)  # Delegate to metaclass implementation

Person.john
Person().john
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU69CgIxDN77FAGXFsTFTXBzFXyDUs7cXaVNSxuHe/paa9UDMVPy/SYuPAfalzI4kzNcMOVAZ2QjeYmoDgLqXHEEraeKMiet5eDyFsj4N/@cmCzxihFinSh9NTfg@K34k57RjT/xCfmeCLqqPdeEqisBNnBCh5NhBA7w6QPro0OPVI02kBCv/t0tzNR3qdpVygM)

Note that you need to implement a delegating version on the class itself to ensure it delegates back to the metaclass's implementation (assuming you want to be able to have it function on instances of the class, not just on the class itself). The metaclass itself could dynamically attach such a method to the class at construction time (in `__prepare__` or `__new__`) if all instances of the metaclass's classes should exhibit this delegation behavior.